# ROS urdf_to_graphiz counterpart in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

is there a tool in gazebo equal to the function of ROS urdf_to_graphiz to get a visual overview of your sdf model?

Thanks for your help,

Christoph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5015/ros-urdf_to_graphiz-counterpart-in-gazebo/) by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is no equivalent. Here is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/958) to track this enhancement.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on 2013-11-18**:
Hey Nate, thank you for your answer. I just stumbled over that, because I thought it could be nice to have an overview of one's model like the urdf graph. Cheers Christoph